# How can I sort nested array by alphabetical order with php?

Tags: php

I have the following data:

```
{
    "Flat": {
        "id": 40,
        "created_at": "2021-07-12 17:04:12",
        "updated_at": "2021-07-12 17:04:12",
        "product_type": "Plate Hats",
        "product_tag": "Plate Hat Production",
        "layout": "plate template.ai",
        "dept": "UV",
        "setup": "multi-flat"
    },
    "Washington City": {
        "productTemplate": {
            "id": 914,
            "created_at": "2019-03-26 16:58:23",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-26 16:58:23",
            "name": "Washington City",
            "template": "prt_Washington.ai",
            "fonts": "1",
            "custom_text": "2",
            "r": "34",
            "g": "42",
            "b": "86",
            "top": "41",
            "spacing": "89",
            "relationId": null,
            "aWidth": null,
            "aHeight": null,
            "productGroup": "40",
            "shopifyId": "169405808664"
        },
        "colorVariants": false
    },
    "Kansas City": {
        "productTemplate": {
            "id": 915,
            "created_at": "2019-03-26 16:58:23",
            "updated_at": "2019-03-26 16:58:23",
            "name": "Kansas City",
            "template": "prt_Washington-DC.ai",
            "fonts": "1",
            "custom_text": "2",
            "r": "42",
            "g": "78",
            "b": "157",
            "top": "49",
            "spacing": "75",
            "relationId": null,
            "aWidth": null,
            "aHeight": null,
            "productGroup": "40",
            "shopifyId": "1308169306180"
        },
        "colorVariants": false
    },
...
```

I would like to sort this based on the field "Flat", "Washington City", etc.
The issue is these are dynamic and there's about 300 of them.  I've seen several answers suggesting using usort but there is always a field that is identified in example "id" in this data.

Here is an example of doing it with "title" as the field.  But again here I don't kno

```
usort($your_array, function ($elem1, $elem2) {
     return strcmp($elem1['title'], $elem2['title']);
});
```

Any idea how I can accomplish this?

Comment: The question is unclear, what’s the problem with id field? What’s wrong with usort?

Comment: You can use uksort: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uksort.php

Comment: There's no `title` field, what do you expect that to do? It seem like you just want `ksort()`, it sorts an associative array by the keys.

Comment: `Flat`, `Washington City`, etc are not fields of the array, they're the array keys.

Comment: @Barmar ok got it so the question should be sort by array keys and use ksort right?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I said in my first comment.